# Multiple Types of Contributions using CiviContributions Drupal Integration

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

I am trying to use one webform to collect multiple types of contributions from one contact. Specifically, we are trying to collect a sponsorship and in-kind donation for one event from one contact type on the same webform. While I don't need to access two different contribution pages, I do want the webforms to population two different contribution records one for the monetary sponsorship, and another with the value of the in-kind donation. Does anyone know how to set this up?

Thanks,
Neena

Comment: I'll let others who are more knowledgeable answer definitively but: I don't think this is possible.  You may want to consider having a single contribution with two line items instead.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Price Set with multiple fields and set the contribution type for each field.  The use that price set on your page.  It will show up as one contribution, but when you click on it and click view you'll see the 2 different contributions and the amount for each type.  You can setup a report to view the info separately for each type if you want.